# Disable the Battery Charging in android after reach 100%

Tags: android

Can I Cut The Battery Charging pro-grammatically in Android Devices? How can i achieve this one without rooting the device.

Comment: AFAIK, this is an in-built feature, You dont need to code for it.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem possible. Please take a look at this question for more detailed discussion
[How to stop an android device from being charged programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654189/how-to-stop-an-android-device-from-being-charged-programmatically)